# Asp.net MVC 2 Multilang Database Model and View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create a multilang mvc application.

My Database Design tablei is
Table : **Group**
GrpID    : Int PK
IsActive : Bit

Table : **GroupDetail**
GrpID  : Int FK
GrpText : Nvarchar(200)
LangID  : Int

**Question 1**
How can I have this view Result.
Francais   English
Auto            Car
Chien       Dog

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you already have a database design. The first thing is to decide how are you going to access this database. You have many choices here. For example you could use an ORM such as [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateforNET) or [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx). If you think that using an ORM for such a simple database schema would be an overkill you could also resort to plain [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=VS.71).aspx) and write the SQL queries yourself. Even in this case it is recommended to setup an object model that will reflect your database schema.

The next step is to write the data access layer. Usually this consists of two parts: an abstraction (interface) and implementation (concrete class) for a given data access technology you picked up in the first step.

Then you write a controller that will talk to this repository and fill a view model. This view model is then passed to the view to be displayed.

Comment: First of all, I leave WebForm to try MVC. Normaly I create my own SQL Query in Stored Procedure then I call it in a class.
My question is. Is ORM is more appropriate with MVC than Stored Procedure call. My only concern with ORM is about flexibility.  I'm not sure you can make big query like in SP : EX (Select * from test Cross apply .......)

There is a lot of post with Linq To Sql. It could be the way to go for my project.

Thanks Darin.

Comment: ORM has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. The choice of using or not an ORM framework is not at all related to MVC. Most ORMs support calling stored procedures so I guess it won't be a problem but of course it is not the natural use of an ORM so probably plain old ADO.NET would be more adapted if you only have stored procedures and write the SQL queries anyway.

Comment: Oh, I see now the difference between ORM or ADO.Net. You absolutely right about ORM Stored procedure support. 

Thanks for the answer , I appreciate it.